# Assign value using % symbol in if match is found Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to understand the following code of how it actually works.I got a text file for example as below which shows the owner of the folder.If Folder A exits it will says that it belongs to Father.

```
Folder A=Father
Folder B=Mother
Folder C=Son
```

code:

```
my %family= ();
$member{"Folder A"} = "Father";
$member{"Folder B"} = "Mother";
$member{"Folder C"} = "Son";
```

I receive advice from my friend saying that the code above will help me to assign the equal value to $member if the ${} is found which I don't quite get logic of how it works and how it assign.

I have other ways to perform the logic above is that I `ls` the outer folder assign to an array then cat the text file assign to an array as well .Then use two for loop and a pattern matching to get the value if the folder exits.But I wanted to know how the above code works as well.Can someone provide example code of how the logic above works and what is the term use for this method called?

---

I made some research and do some of the code but there are some issues in the code where i cannot get the hash information when I assign variable to extract.

```
%family;
@family_list = `cat /data/admin/family/Family_name.txt`;
@FOLDER=`cd /data/admin/family/;ls -d */ | cut -f1 -d'/'`;
foreach $item(@family_list)
{
   @temp = split ( /=/, $item);
   $family{$temp[0]}=$temp[1];
}

foreach $item(@FOLDER)
{
   print "$item";
   $member=$family{$item};
   print "$member";
}
```

The `foreach $item loop` part it seems like the `$member` was not assign with any output from the `%family`.I tried to hard code and it displayed the family member for example `$member=$family{"Folder A"}` which in result print father.Can someone point out my mistake that I performed ?I check the web and their example are mostly hard coded .

Comment: The "`%` symbol" in Perl is a hash. Google "perl hash".

Comment: Have a good read about hashes here: http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/03-perl-language.html#SGFzaGVz

Comment: How to extract the hash if I declared it as variable .I tried hard code it manage to print it but it seems that it does not work that way when I assign it as variable .I post my code above .